# How to find and prioritize words from a given Enum list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, enums

I have an ENUM defined as follows:

```
 public enum TextType {
     JOIN,
     SUBSCRIBE,
     STOP,
     HELP,
     CANCEL,
     UNSUBSCRIBE,
     UPGRADE,
     BALANCE,
     USAGE
  }
```

I would like to prioritize this and filter it as follows:

Yes (if phone is not yet verified to receive text then accept this text; else ignore and go to the next one) 
  stop, cancel, unsubscribe
  Help
  Balance or USAGE
  UPGRADE

So basically when the User sends a Text say "YES BALANCE" then internally first I do a check to see if the phone number
 is registered. If registered then I should use the text "Balance" and return the balance. But if the phone us unregistered
 then I should use the text "YES" to register the phone first and ignore the rest. 
 My issue is currently I am using the Enum.IsDefined to find out if the above is a valid Text and since we have two 
 different texts combined it fails right away.

```
 if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TextType), VtextType))
```

So how do I rewrite the below IF condition in C# so that I am able to accept both 'Yes' and 'Balance'. Should I change the definition of my Enum or should I use "contains" or should I use regex? I am using .Net4.5

Please help.

After Michaels reply can I loop through the string of array as:

```
foreach (string s in Tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are receiving a plain text message that you need to parse for a set of instructions.  Once you've parsed the instructions, you can then traverse a representative data structure such as an array or abstract syntax tree and make decisions.

Without knowing the full syntax of the messages you're receiving, I can only guess at the best way to parse them.  Some options are:

- Split the message by whitespace into an array of tokens and loop through the tokens
- Use a more sophisticated grammar parsing library such as [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/)

Enums may come in handy when defining the set of tokens you're able to parse.

---

Update: If you're just looking to split up the string and look at each word (or token), you can use something like:

```
var Tokens = Regex.Split(myString, @"\s+");
```

Now you have an array of strings, and you can look at each string in the array individually.  You could see if the first string is "YES", try to parse each string as your Enum, etc.

Comment: We can get the text as "Yes Balance" Or text as 'Yes' or just as 'Balance'. Does this help?

Comment: Then just split the text on whitespace and look at the terms in the resulting string array.

Comment: So would I use something like myString.split(/[\s\W]+/)

Comment: Also if I want only the first word or the second word in case I need to skip the Yes then how do I pass that to split?

Comment: Thank you. I think this would work. But to look at each string in the array individually do I need to loop through or can i use it explicitly as Token[1] etc? New to .net and so not sure how to loop through a string of array. Please advise. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Updated my code above. Please see if that is correct.